# Why is "local launch" allowed for out-proc servers by default but "local activation" is not?

Tags: windows, security, com, dcom

I currently need to create a COM object that is served by an out-proc COM server from inside an ASP.NET handler. So every time I deploy the COM server I have to fire up DCOM Config and change the security settings. Specifically I need to ensure that both "local launch" and "local activation" is allowed fro the local user ASPNET.

What surprises me is that when I open the relevant settings page "local launch" is already allowed but "local activation" is not allowed.

That doesn't make sense - why would I need such combination of permissions?

Comment: I assume they are set to "default" and when you switch to "customize" and "edit" you see this?

Comment: @Tony Lee: Yes, exactly.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to guess it's because that's what your default is set to.  It's not normal as far as I'm concerned so I don't know how it got messed up.

You can set the default permissions in dcomcnfg by looking at the properties of "my computer" under the COM Security tab.  I think you'll find your COM server's user's default permissions under "Edit Defaults" for Launch and Activation Permissions doesn't have local activation checked.