# Is it possible to deploy an out-proc COM server on Windows Azure and alter its activation permission?

Tags: windows, deployment, com, azure, cloud

I need to consume an out-proc COM server from both a worker role and a web role in a Windows Azure application. One step I'm almost sure I'll need to do is [to alter the access permissions for the COM server](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5946520/57428) - grant "local launch" and "local activation" permissions for the predefined user under which roles code executes.

So far I found there's [DCOMPERM](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/206484) utility in Windows SDK samples which contains code that I guess would do that. So I could write similar code and package it into either a separate executable or into the COM registration code of the COM server and [run that code from a role start-up task](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5976974/57428). That's not trivial, but certainly doable.

I only have one major concern before I start.

Are there any reasons why I can't do that? Maybe using out-proc COM servers is not allowed on Windows Azure or something? Are there any such limitations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Are there any reasons why I can't do that? Maybe using out-proc COM servers is not allowed on Windows Azure or something? Are there any such limitations?

It's not something I've personally done, but if you can install a COM+ server running in a shell exe, then I think you should be able to do what you want - see this recent blog post http://michaelwasham.com/2011/05/15/deploying-a-com-servicedcomponent-to-windows-azure/

I don't think you will hit limitations - but I think you will hit a fair few problems along the way - good luck.

Comment: Two years later I can confirm that there're positively no problems with this approach. Writing code was a usual bit of stress but it all just works in the end.